# Compile libxml2 get "error: storage size of ‘hints’ isn’t known"

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gcc, libxml2

I download libxml2 2.9.4 in [here](http://xmlsoft.org/sources), when i `./configure; make`, i get following error:

```
nanohttp.c: In function ‘xmlNanoHTTPConnectHost’:
nanohttp.c:1073:18: error: storage size of ‘hints’ isn’t known
  struct addrinfo hints, *res, *result;
                  ^
nanohttp.c:1079:11: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getaddrinfo’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  status = getaddrinfo (host, NULL, &hints, &result);
           ^
nanohttp.c:1079:2: warning: nested extern declaration of ‘getaddrinfo’ [-Wnested-externs]
  status = getaddrinfo (host, NULL, &hints, &result);
  ^
nanohttp.c:1085:35: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct addrinfo’
  for (res = result; res; res = res->ai_next) {
                                   ^
nanohttp.c:1089:7: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘freeaddrinfo’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
       freeaddrinfo (result);
       ^
nanohttp.c:1089:7: warning: nested extern declaration of ‘freeaddrinfo’ [-Wnested-externs]
nanohttp.c:1073:18: warning: unused variable ‘hints’ [-Wunused-variable]
  struct addrinfo hints, *res, *result;
                  ^
```

the full output is [here](https://gist.github.com/roroco/1d2cf04ad6b4c45c5bddc3249d882ed9)

here is my environment:

```
roroco@roroco ~/Downloads $ lsb_release  -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa
Release:    17.3
Codename:   rosa
roroco@roroco ~/Downloads $ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.8.5-2ubuntu1~14.04.1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.5 (Ubuntu 4.8.5-2ubuntu1~14.04.1)
```

I try version 2.9.2 and 2.9.3, i get same error, how to compile libxml2 success?

Comment: The first lines in `man getaddrinfo` show: `#include <sys/types.h>
       #include <sys/socket.h>
       #include <netdb.h>`

Comment: Did `./configure` succeed?

Comment: @alk yes, of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution:

in nanohttp.c, the error line:

```
#if defined(HAVE_GETADDRINFO) && (defined(SUPPORT_IP6) || defined(_WIN32))
    {
    int status;
    struct addrinfo hints, *res, *result;
```

so i can disable ipv6 to don't compile this block code. I try following code will work:

```
./configure --enable-ipv6=no LIBS="-lpthread"; make
```

I find "--enable-ipv6" in "libxml2-src/configure"

Answer (score 1):

For using "getaddrinfo" you must use POSIX. 
For clean C, use ***`gcc flag -std=gnu11`*** or ***`-std=gnu99`*** instead **`с11/с99`**.
Checking for POSIX you can using this code:

```
#ifdef  __USE_POSIX
    #warning POSIX compatible
#else
    #warning no support POSIX
#endif
```